# How to read coordinates in this specific format

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, shapely, fiona

I'm trying to create a shapefile consisting of lines from my python output. The output of the function is :

```
[[[400 421 427 114]]

[[227 475 237 356]]

[[408 383 427 124]]

[[456 322 500 327]]

[[436  68 441   8]]]
```

Where [X coord start point, y start point, x end point, y end point]

I've tried Shapely and Fiona but I can't get it to read this format.
How to iterate between the coordinates and putting them into a shapefile?

Comment: Do you have some code where you tried to put those numbers in shapefiles?

Comment: Yeah I tried a couple of things but it didn't lead anywhere, so i don't think it's very useful to share.

Comment: Indeed it is, that way we can help you with your code instead of writing the whole solution.

Comment: Yeah okay, I wasn't really looking for a whole code, but more a direction of software or libraries that can help me accomplish it.

Comment: @Squaree you are on the right path using shapely and fiona, but as Mazu_R said we need to see what you tried to complete it or correct where it is wrong ;)

Comment: Alright, I already got the answer btw! Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: By all means, post your solution as an answer, @Squaree. It will be useful to others with a similar question.